# Segments with most points algorithm analysis

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

We define x1, x2,..., x_n to be a sequence of points (numbers) and [s_i, t_i] be a set of n segments for 1 ≤ i ≤ n. Point x_j is inside the segment i if s_i ≤ x_j ≤ t_i. I want to find the segment with the most points.

Now to solve this, I am thinking we can sort x and the intervals based on s. Keep a separate array, T, such that T[i] = maximum points in the segment i. Initialize all the values in this array to 0. Then, for each x, check all the intervals that fit the constraint and increment T[i] accordingly.

This in the worst case scenario can take O(n^2). But I feel like I have a lot of redundancy here. How do I make this more efficient?

Comment: Are these "points" actually just numbers? If not, what does it mean for a point to be less than another? Also, are all `s_i` and `t_i` in the set `X`?

Comment: Are these "segments" actually just intervals?

Comment: Yes, you can assume their just numbers.

Comment: We can assume that no segment is completely included in any other segment; otherwise, the containing segment will include potentially more points.

Comment: Yes, assume all s_i and t_i and x_i are distinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify, if you problem is one-dimensional, the points in `X` (`x_1` to `x_n`) are numbers, and the segments are intervals.

You can easily solve this by sorting `X` and using the resulting indices. You can effectively calculate the number of points within a segment `[s, t]` by finding the two corresponding indices `i` and `j`. Find (using binary-search or whatever is most efficient) `i` such that `x_i < s <= x_(i+1)`, and `j` such that `x_j <= t < x_(j+1)`. Note the inequalities (in case `s` or `t` might be in `X`). The number of points within `[s, t]` is equal to `j-i`.

If it is possible that `s < x_1` or `t > x_n`, simply append a point to both ends of `X` (a minimum and a maximum).

This has complexity `O(n log n)`, limited by the sorting algorithm. If you can use something like counting sort that uses the values as indices into an array (or keys into a multiset), then you can improve on that by doing some more work.

Let `S` be the set of points containing every `s` and every `t` for all the segments `[s, t]`. The idea is to build an indexing array for `X` (kind of like for a counting sort).

First, build the array `A` such that `A[x in X] = 1` and `A[x not in X] = 0`. Then, go through it again to build the array `A_less` such that `A_less[i]` equals the sum of all `A[j]` with `j < i`.
For example, if `A = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]`, then `A_less = [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]`. You can build this array using a simple counter.

You can now refer directly to this array to get the number of points which values are less than or equal to another. In the previous example, there are clearly three points in `X`, with values 0, 3, and 5. By refering to `A_less`, you can know that there are `A_less[4] = 2` points with values less than or equal to 4.

Similarly, build `A_less_equal` such that `A_less_equal[i]` equals the sum of all `A[j]` with `j <= i`. Using the same example, `A_less_equal = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]`.

Now, for any segment `[s, t]`, you can get the number of points it contains by computing `A_less_equal[t] - A_less[s]`. All of that has complexity `O(n)`.

If your points are not integers (are at least, not easily usable as indices), then you can still use the same idea, replacing the arrays with sorted sets, the keys of which are every value in `X` or `S` (you need to add the values in `S` to be able to look them up at the end).

Comment: Can you expand on why we have "`i` such that `x_i < s <= x_(i+1)`..."

Comment: You mean find the right most element that's less than s, right?

Comment: Take an example: `X = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, s = 2, t = 3`, you expect the result to be 2. If you take `i = 1`, then `x_i = 1 < s = 2 <= x_(i+1) = 2`. And for the other end, take `j = 3` which means `x_j = 3 <= t = 3 < x_(j+1) = 4`. You get `j - i = 2`, as expected. Yes, that's the right-most element that is less than `s` (and the right-most element that is less than or equal to `t`).

Comment: @Jonathan There, I added a more efficient but more complicated solution.